# How to copy file from local to a directory in namenode Docker?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to copy a file from local to a directory in the namenode in `docker`. I tried this command : `docker cp ./ventes.txt ID:/~/direc1` but the file doesn't exists when i access the directory in the namenode bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a problem by using "*~*". Could you try to use an absolute path?
For example:

```sh
docker cp ./ventes.txt 6c25a78e8f59:/root/direc1
```